# Radgrid Passing parameter to NeedDatasource

Tags: c#, telerik, datasource, radgrid

I want to be able to pass a parameter to grid_NeedDataSource.

```
RadGrid.NeedDataSource += new GridNeedDataSourceEventHandler(grid_NeedDataSource(Parameter i want to pass));

  void grid_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e, DataTable dt)
    {
        DataTable current = dt;
        RadGrid grid = (RadGrid)sender;
        grid.DataSource = current;
    }
```

I want to be able to pass it a DataTable as a parameter. How would i be able to do that?

Comment: The short answer is you can't.  Is dt not available to the object handling the event?

Comment: no it won't let me, but i remember that there is a way to do something like this, i just can't remember how to do it exactly, (sender, e) => (sender, e, dt) or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Radgrid1.NeedDataSource += new GridNeedDataSourceEventHandler((sender, e) => grid_NeedDataSource(sender, e, "new parameter"));

protected void grid_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e, string t)
{
}
```

**Edit:** In order to pass a `DataTable`, you can do like that:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
Radgrid1.NeedDataSource += new GridNeedDataSourceEventHandler((sender, e) => grid_NeedDataSource(sender, e, dt));

protected void grid_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e, DataTable t)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried that, and it compiles fine, but it doesn't seem to load the datatable when i pass it like that, could it be that they have restriction to prevent that?